# how to create userframe in python opencv

Tags: python

i try to find the contour of the object using this code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
  
# Let's load a simple image with 3 black squares
image = cv2.imread('C://Users//gfg//shapes.jpg')
cv2.waitKey(0)
  
# Grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  
# Find Canny edges
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200)
cv2.waitKey(0)
  
# Finding Contours
# Use a copy of the image e.g. edged.copy()
# since findContours alters the image
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged, 
    cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
  
cv2.imshow('Canny Edges After Contouring', edged)
cv2.waitKey(0)
  
print("Number of Contours found = " + str(len(contours)))
  
# Draw all contours
# -1 signifies drawing all contours
cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
  
cv2.imshow('Contours', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I try to make a userframe so that contours is relative to new userframe (right now contour is relative to camera frame-0-640 and 0-480)
the new frame can be 5,5   -  10,6    -    7,10   -  15,12